# How to make Intellij follow sbt GitHub dependencies?

Tags: scala, github, intellij-idea, sbt, intellij-plugin

I managed how to add github dependencies to my sbt project following the instructions in this [link](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/using-github-projects-scala-library-dependencies-sbt-sbteclipse).
However, Intellij could not find the github dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After om-nom-nom sugestion, only Scala plugin is needed:

1. Installing the Scala plugin from a fresh idea install
2. Import project from external model -> SBT project
3. ? use auto import ?
4. Register "unregistered Vcs root"
5. Set module SDK with your JDK folder and adopt it for the project
6. Write a main file and press ctrl+shift+F10

The step 4 is important because you won't need to keep the working copies of the sub-projects anymore.
Idea creates them inside ~/.IdeaIC13 folder.

This [link](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/08/git-branches-for-multi-root-projects/) talks about multi-root Projects and synchronous branch control.

ps. the SBT plugin somehow was disabled and ideia became cofused about a subproject with a (nested) subsubproject.

Comment: Does it really helps? IIRC, it only provides shortcut to console and do not manages dependencies in any way.